# Wrap word to a certain limit in td

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the `td`'s css `wrap-wrap` as `break-word`. As the word gets wrapped the `td`'s height is increasing. But i need to increase the height(as i enter the text) of the `td` to a  certain limit and remaining text should be hidden.

The text which is exceeding the height should not be visible, but we can enter the as long as text we require.
Is there a way to achieve the scenario.

It is similar to applying wrap text and merge cell to same cells in excel.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function(){
 $('td').attr('contenteditable','true');
});
```

```css
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
table-layout:fixed;
width:500px;
}
td{
position:relative;
border: 2px solid black;
-webkit-user-select:none;
width:25%;
height:20px;
overflow:ellipsis;
word-wrap: break-word;
padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit contenteditable div height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869111/limit-contenteditable-div-height)

Comment: `div` behaves differently compared to `td`. I dont want to stop entering text i want to hide the remaining text and wrapped text should be limited height.

Comment: @StarkButtowski why don't you have div inside TD for making it contenteditable

Comment: you can try it in table tag styles like   `style="table-layout: fixed;"` and in that td you can give custom width and height and make the   `overflow`   property of td as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you should probably just use divs for your layout and do away with the table altogether.

But, if you have to use a table, since `tds` behave differently than `divs`, you could insert a div into each td like this:

```js
$('td').append('<div class="faux-cell">');
$fauxCells=$('.faux-cell');
$fauxCells.attr('contenteditable', 'true');
$fauxCells.each(function(){
  $this= $(this);
  $this.css('max-width',$this.parent().width());
});
$fauxCells.on('keypress', function(e) {
  var element = this;
  if ((element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)) {
    e.stop();
  }
});
```

```css
.faux-cell {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
}
.red {
  color: #ff0000;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
}
td {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  width: 25%;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Note the change to `overflow:hidden;`**